# MySQL error 1054 unknown column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables.

1. t_problem
2. t_riesenia

In t_problem I have primary key `id`.
In t_riesenia I have foreign key `ProblemID`. At least I think I have.
I want to select all fields from table `t_problem` where there is a solution in `t_riesenia` (there is a`ProblemID` in `t_riesenia` equal to `id` in `t_problem`)

When trying to execute SQL statement :

```
SELECT * FROM `t_problem` where `t_problem`.`id`=`t_riesenia`.`ProblemID`
```

I get an error :

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't_riesenia.ProblemID' in 'where clause'

Why? See screenshots from MySQL workbench below.

**t_problem**
[image: t_problem]

**t_riesenia**
[image: t_riesenia]

**t_riesenia Foreign key**
[image: t_riesenia Foreign key]

Comment: You should join with `t_riesenia` table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using an explicit `join`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM t_problem p JOIN
     t_riesenia r
      ON p.id = r.ProblemID;
```

It is also possible that you intend an `IN`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM t_problem p
WHERE p.id IN (SELECT r.ProblemID FROM t_riesenia r);
```

The difference between the two is how duplicates are handled in `t_riesenia`.  The first returns duplicate rows.  The second does not.

Answer (score 1):

That column may exist *somewhere in your database*, but it doesn't exist *in your query*.  You query specifies only one table:

```
SELECT * FROM `t_problem` where `t_problem`.`id`=`t_riesenia`.`ProblemID`
```

Note the `FROM` clause has only a single table.  You can see it a little more clearly if you structure it explicitly:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `t_problem`
WHERE
    `t_problem`.`id`=`t_riesenia`.`ProblemID`
```

The only known table in this query is `t_problem`.  In order to add more tables, they need to be added to the `FROM` clause.  Something like this, for example:

```
SELECT
    `t_problem`.*
FROM
    `t_problem`
    INNER JOIN `t_riesenia` ON `t_problem`.`id` = `t_riesenia`.`ProblemID`
```

(Note that in this case the `WHERE` clause isn't really needed, since that comparison is going to be true for every joined record.)